# Is there an expression in english for when a woman loses the desire just before the sex happens?

Tags: expressions

I hope it's not aggressive to say here the expression "go limp", that's the expression I heard of for a men when he fail on sex. Can I use the same expression for woman? Or is there another one?

Comment: "Cock tease" comes close.

Comment: Was she perhaps experiencing [vaginal dryness](https://www.bustle.com/articles/54182-why-is-my-vagina-dry-during-sex-and-what-can-i-do-to-make-it-wet)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes... And maybe that's the term... I mean when she, for any reason (maybe something she remembered) lose the desire, and can't go on.

Comment: Are you looking for a medical term, something used in everyday language, slang, or a vulgar or derogatory term?

Comment: @fixer1234 Medical term? Just try shouting out "I feel a headache coming on". Works every time.

Comment: @fixer1234 everyday language.

Comment: She got _turned off_. Cocktease means intentionally seducing and rejecting.